# Add a separator after some condition in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a chat window in which I want to add a horizontal separator when ever a new date appears in a specific column of list binded as an item source of datagrid. Is it possible?.If it is then how?
any help will be appreciated.

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provided examples of your code. As it is, I can suggest handling `PropertyChanged` event if your list implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (if not, make sure it does).

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I have just written code for chat and not tried any thing for separator yet.Because I cant figure any thing out.If you want code of chat I can give you that.I have made a datagrid with 3 column.In two of them I am showing picture and message and in third,I am showing time.What I want to do is add a separator after every new date in that list

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense, ignore my previous comment then. Logically you want to group messages, so I'd look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I think you can create a grouping element without an expander, so it should be OK.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Can you please tell me how can I make the second group conditional?

Comment: Which second group? In what sense conditional?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova When ever the date of message changes from the last one then seprator should be added

Comment: If you group messages by date (that is by day "Today,Tuesday, ect.") each time the date changes you've got a new group which has its own header. In your case you put a line and a textbox in the header. Thus each day will be separated by a line. You don't need any conditions, just grouping. What you need to do is to add a field to group by, which will return 'Today', 'Tuesday', 'A week ago' and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked it, yes you can go with grouping:

a) add a new property to the object which represent message. This property will return a string value depending on the date (something like `DayOfWeek.ToString();`)

b) group your collection be this new property (using `<CollectionViewSource>`)

c) Set a style for a group, roughly like this (you'll need to add a canvas or something with a line and probably bind DockPanel's width to it's parent width):

```
  <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                                            <!-- here comes the line -->
                                        </DockPanel>
                                        <ListBox>
                                            <ListBox.Items>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </ListBox.Items>
                                        </ListBox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>              
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

P.S. It won't work of course if you want to group messages older than a week with the same pattern. In this case you can try to group by two properties. I'd put everything in "older" though.